# Is a function containing an await considered synchronous?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I was reading about [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await#:%7E:text=Async%2Fawait%20makes%20your%20code,would%20with%20a%20synchronous%20operation.) over at MDN, specifically, the downsides of using it as the link points out.

From my understanding, any method that implements `async/await` will be treated, for all intents and purposes, as synchronous whereas calling code will continue, treating that method as asynchronous. Is this a fair assessment? It seems odd to say that `myAsyncFunction` is synchronous but maybe that's the correct terminology.

```
async function myAsyncFunction(): Promise<void> {
    await client.someRequest();
    // code below will wait for the above to resolve
}

function callingCode(): void {
    myAsyncFunction();
    /// code below will happen asynchronously and not wait for above to resolve
}
```

Comment: It's still asynchronous. `await` simply pauses the function until the awaited value is resolved. The function *has* to be asynchronous for this to work, as when it's paused other code can be executed before the value it's awaiting is resolved. So if you call `asyncFn(); syncFn();` then the second function *definitely* finishes and produces a value before `asyncFn` even if it's called after it.

Comment: Your use of terms is a bit off but the comments in your code are correct.